# Install pip3 for Python 3.6.3 only

Tags: linux-mint, python3, pip

I freshly installed Linux Mint 18.3 on my laptop. Mint 18.3 ships with default Python version 3.5.2. Since, I need to work in Python3.6.3, I grabbed a tar ball from Python.org and installed it with following commands:

```
$ cd Python3.6.3
./configure
make
make test
sudo make install
```

Then in terminal when I type python3, it gives following output:

```
linuxsagar@Satellite-P755 ~ $ python3
Python 3.6.3 (default, Jan 21 2018, 19:33:32) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Which is totally fine. Then I installed pip.

```
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
```

I expect that pip is installed for python3.6.3, but while executing pip3 -V it gives:

> ```
> pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (python 3.5)
> ```

How do I install pip only for python3.6.3?

Comment: It's not a good idea to try to change the default Python version installed by the OS because several system scripts may depend on the specific version. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122818/how-can-i-change-the-default-version-on-python-on-linux-in-order-to-install-and

Comment: Do `which python3` and add that path to your `.bashrc` file

Comment: See [Python 3.6 - install latest version into Linux Mint](https://mintguide.org/other/794-python-3-6-install-latest-version-into-linux-mint.html) for a PPA packaged version of python 3.6 for Mint 18.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I very much doubt that Mint will keep versions of PIP in the repositories for versions of Python they don't also have in the repositories. However, from [this python.org page on PIP](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#ensure-you-can-run-pip-from-the-command-line):

> If you installed Python from source, with an installer from
>   python.org, or via Homebrew you should already have pip. If you’re on
>   Linux and installed using your OS package manager, you may have to
>   install pip separately, see Installing pip/setuptools/wheel with Linux
>   Package Managers.

So in theory you should already have it if you have compiled and installed with make install. Try using `locate` or `find` for `pip3.6`

incidentally, the [python site](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/unix.html#building-python) gives the following warning.

> Warning
>
> make install can overwrite or masquerade the python3 binary. make
>   altinstall is therefore recommended instead of make install since it
>   only installs exec_prefix/bin/pythonversion